# rviz error wxWidgets couldn't load a png image

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I am trying to run rviz and get this response. I have upgraded libpng, but with no result:

```
trurl@trurl:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1316992589.920372061]: rviz revision number 1.6.4
[ INFO] [1316992589.920459084]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1316992589.920486881]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1316992589.969539903]: Loading general config from [/home/trurl/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1316992589.969961674]: Loading display config from [/home/trurl/.rviz/display_config]

[ WARN] [1316992589.973563250]: wxWidgets Warning [Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.2.42]

[ WARN] [1316992589.973616050]: wxWidgets Warning [Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.4.3]

[ WARN] [1316992589.973658653]: wxWidgets Warning [Incompatible libpng version in application and library]

[ERROR] [1316992589.973709637]: wxWidgets Error [Couldn't load a PNG image - file is corrupted or not enough memory.]
```

Best Regards,

Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11307/rviz-error-wxwidgets-couldn%27t-load-a-png-image/) by [Robotnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1119/robotnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-26**:
Can you edit your question to state what OS you're running and what version of libpng is installed on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had exactly the same error message. Deleting the entire .rviz directory in the home directory fixed the problem for us.

---

Originally posted by [Andrew Gee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1335/andrew-gee/) with karma: 81 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0